# 'Soft' move to HTTPS

Tags: performance, mobile, ssl, https

I have a mobile site that I generally want to always be all HTTPS.  It uses the HTML5 application cache to store all the data locally so its a fast user experience EXCEPT during the first page view.

My homepage will load on an iPhone over 4G ATT in 1 second without HTTPS and in 4.5 seconds with HTTPS (round trip time latency is the killer here).  So, I am trying to find a way to softly move the user to HTTPS so they have a great first impression, followed by a secure experience.

Here is what I am doing:

- Externally, always referencing HTTP (ie press releases, etc)
- canonical = HTTP (so Google see HTTP)
- On the site pages all links are HTTPS
- Once the user comes to the HTTP page the HTTPS pages (all of them) will load via an application cache manifest in an iFrame
- Upon hitting the server for the first time (HTTP), the server will set a cookie, and the next time force a redirect to HTTPS (which is already cached)

Is this a good implementation to get the speed of HTTP with the security of HTTPS?